# Process builder to exclude queue when sending email alerts

Tags: queue, process, builder

I have a Process builder to trigger email alerts for users when lead source is deal.
I am having issues when i try to exclude queue members on the email alert.I get the following error when i update the process flow criteria to exclude owner id contains Left(owner id, 3) = '00G' or i use the developer name and update the owner to the queue.
'An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow, An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow'

Comment: try creating a formula checkbox field on Lead called `Is_Owned_by_Queue__c` and then have PB filter on that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create a formula field of Text type with the Owner.Type and check that field value. If the field value is User send the email alert. Though there is no direct way to get the value in formula field but below can be used to get it

```
IF( ISBLANK( Owner:User.Id ), 'QUEUE', 'USER' )
```

Now you can use that value to run your process.

[image]
[image]